# How to respond to "shown.bs.collapse" event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I search on the web, but unfortunately, nothing works for me.

I tried many different ways to respond to "shown.bs.collapse" event, but it never fires.

I tried by replacing ".collapse" by "#divi", or by changing the place of the event binding from the bottom to the top, but nothing did it.

Here is my current code :

```
<button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#divi">Click</button>
<div id="divi" class="collapse">
  Masqued
</div>
<script>
$(".collapse").on("shown.bs.collapse", function() {
  alert("test");
});
</script>
```

I just wrote a new simple html file thanks to the answer of Jaganathan Bantheswaran :

```
<script>
$(".collapse").on("shown.bs.collapse", function() {
  alert("test");
});
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#divi">Click</button>
<div id="divi" class="collapse">
  Masqued
</div>
```

And it doesn't works too.

Comment: What are trying to do ? Is that html for a tab ?

Comment: I want to change a content dynamically when the user finishes the opening of the collapsible element

Comment: Why dont you use bootstrap tab ?

Comment: It's html to change the content of an other element when the user opens the collapsible element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same code works fine with the bootstrap version 3.3.7. Which version of bootstrap you are in?

## Update 1

In your code sample, The event linking for `shown.bs.collapse` has to go down to the page. Because the none of the libs would be loaded at that time of event registration.

```js
$(".collapse").on("shown.bs.collapse", function() {
  alert("test");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#divi">Click</button>
<div id="divi" class="collapse">
  Masqued
</div>
```

Comment: I am currently on Bootstrap 3.3.7 too.
It's strange ! What you just wrote works very well, but in my application, it doesn't works at all.

Comment: Something broken with other scripts i think

Comment: I don't think so, I just wrote a simple file.html with this code, and it doesn't works too.

Comment: The event linking for `shown.bs.collapse` has to go down to the page. Because the none of the lib would not be loaded at that time